# What is the difference between return function and return function object in python?

Tags: python

```
def speak():
    def whisper():
        print('ased')
    return whisper()

speak()
```

While using decorators what we do is return function object, but here we have returned the function (return whisper()), so can someone explain what is the difference between returning a function and returning a function object?

Comment: What's the difference between a function and a function object supposed to be?

Comment: in python everything is an object

Comment: It's not returning a function object, it's returning the result of the function call.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. This code is not even valid

Comment: `return whisper()` doesn't return the function, it returns the value of the expression `whisper()`, which is the result of calling the function

Comment: In python everything is an object so there is no functions there are only function objects. if you want function take a language like c++ then there are functions and function objects( functors).

Comment: @AlbinPaul i think the op is just asking what the difference between `return whisper` vs `return whisper()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing a function that has a nested function inside it. The normal intent of this is that you would have some other code in there more interesting than what you are doing, but I realize this is just a toy for you to try the idea, so we can ignore that.

The real problem you have is the return. You code:

```py
def speak():
    def whisper():
        print('ased')
    return whisper()

speak()
```

has the return statement actually calling the `whisper()` function and then returning the result of that function call, which is nothing since `whisper()` does not return anythin it just prints.

So it is basically the same as if you had written:

```py
def speak():
    return print('ased')

speak()
```

or just:

```py
def speak():
    print('ased')

speak()
```

What you probably intended was to leave off the `()`'s like this `return whisper` so that it did not call the function, but actually returned a reference to the function that would be returned and could later be called, like this:

```py
def speak():
    def whisper():
        print('ased')
    return whisper

func = speak()
...
func()
```

Which would not print anything when speak was called but would return a function reference that you can save and then call later (in this case `func`).

The above is not the way a decorator works, but it does use the same principal of defining an internal function and then returning a reference to that function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you help me out in teaching where I should use Function and where I should use function object?

Comment: I'm not certain but I think I know what you mean. You're not talking about the function definition, but where it gets used, either as `whisper()` or `whisper` without the `()`'s. The difference between these two uses is that in the case of `whisper()` you're calling the function right there in the code where it's used. So the function is called, it does what it does and returns what it returns. Using the form `whisper` (no `()`'s), you're not calling the function at that point. Instead it gives a reference to the function to be saved away and called at a later point via the saved reference.

Answer (score 0):

The return function object, returns the function and in Python can be assigned to another function which also becomes callable function. The new assigned function can be called to perform the same task.

Where as in return function, it returns the value and only the same function will be called to perform the function. It can not be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

when you return the function, it will execute the print('ased') when create a new variable. But if you return the object, you can execute the variable that will perform the same task